# How to stop angular animation?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I use angular animations with delay. When user (mouseover) the component, it expands and when (mouseleave), it collapses.

Here the code of animation:

The states of 'opened' and 'closed' I change in code with mouseover and mouseleave events

```
  animations: [
    trigger('navOpen', [
      state('closed', style({transform: 'scaleX(0)'})),
      state('opened', style({transform: 'scaleX(1)'})),
      transition('void => *', animate(0)),
      transition('closed => open', [
        animate('0.1s 1000ms', style({transform: 'scaleX(1)'})),
      ]),
      transition('open => closed', [
        animate('0.1s', style({transform: 'scaleX(0)'}))
      ])
    ])
  ]
```

The problem is that the component expands with 1000ms delay, and when I mouseover and mouseleave(e.g. within 200ms), it expands after 1000ms anyway. How to stop the animation of expanding if cursor leaves before the animation starts(because of delay)?

Comment: could you create a stackblitz with your issue?

Comment: As you can see from this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3rnky9) it should work as is. If you mouseover the p tag the button will hide, then if you leave it the button will show after a second. But if you return over the p tag before the second has passed the button will not be shown. I think the problem is somewhere else. You should share more code.